# Importing a module with bad characters, for example, "import data-lake"

Tags: python, python-import

I am required to import a package authored by another.  My import statement looks like this:

```
from data-lake.libs.utils.operators import airflow_utils
```

Obviously this throws a syntax error, what would be the work around?

Comment: Is the folder actually named that way? is the author aware of the problems this causes? Can you not simply rename the folder?

Comment: It's cloned from an active repo.  Typically the module is called from within a Docker container, I'm trying to import it in a Python script outside of the container.

Comment: Is the repo public? Could we see it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing

```
airflow_utils = __import__('data-lake.libs.utils.operators').airflow_utils
```

Comment: Not sure if airflow_utils is a module